# JSPDF - background color of rows based on cell values

Tags: handlebars.js, background-color, jspdf-autotable

I'm building a PDF with jspdf and autoTable, and a table build with handlebars from a JSON.

I'm trying to get background color on certain rows, which are based on certain values in a column. Until now I managed to get the background of the cells with the certain values colored. Unfortunately I'm getting stuck now with getting the entire rows of those certain cells colored.

Note: I'm using the code to build visuals in Postman

This is my handlebars table code:

```
<body>
 <div id="container" class="container">
   <table id = "${pm.info.requestId}" table class="row-border" style="width:100%">
     <thead>

            <th>Event Type</th>
            <th>eventId</th>
            <th>validTime</th>
            <th>knowledgeTime</th>
            <th>assetType</th>
            <th>symbol</th>
            <th>longShort</th>
            <th>custodianAccount</th>
            <th>strategy</th>
            <th>manager</th>
            <th>basket</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th>nativeCost</th>
            <th>commission</th>
            <th>fee</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Lot<br>Identifier</th>
            <th>System<br>Action</th>
            <th>COA</th>
            <th>financial<br>Account</th>
            <th>Inventory State</th>
            <th>book cost</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        {{#each response.ledgers}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{eventType}}</td>
            <td>{{eventId}}</td>
            <td>{{validTime}}</td>
            <td>{{knowledgeTime}}</td>
            <td>{{assetType}}</td>
            <td>{{symbol}}</td>
            <td>{{longShort}}</td>
            <td>{{custodianAccount}}</td>
            <td>{{strategy}}</td>
            <td>{{manager}}</td>
            <td>{{basket}}</td>
            <td>{{quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{nativeCost}}</td>
            <td>{{commission}}</td>
            <td>{{fee}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        {{#each journalEntries}}
        {{#each lines}}
        <td>Journal Entries</td>
        <td>{{../../eventId}}</td>
            <td>{{../time}}</td>
            <td>{{../../knowledgeTime}}</td>
            <td>{{assetType}}</td>
            <td>{{symbol}}</td>
            <td>{{longShort}}</td>
            <td>{{custodianAccount}}</td>
            <td>{{strategy}}</td>
            <td>{{manager}}</td>
            <td>{{basket}}</td>
            <td>{{quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{nativeCost}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{icap}}</td>
            <td>{{lotId}}</td>
            <td>{{factType}}</td>
            <td>{{financialAccountType}}</td>
           <td>{{financialAccount}}</td>
            <td>{{inventoryState}}</td>
            <td>{{bookCost}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
     </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

And my PDF code

```
<script>
    function generate() {
        //Creation of PDF document
        let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');

        const totalPagesExp = '{total_pages_count_string}';

  var elem = document.getElementById('${pm.info.requestId}');
  var data = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
  doc.autoTable(data.columns, data.rows, { 
  theme: 'plain',
    styles: {
        fontSize: 10,
        font: 'Montserrat'
    },

     didParseCell: function (data) {
                    if(data.cell.text.indexOf('EQUITY_CLOSE_LONG') > -1) {
                        data.cell.styles.fillColor = [216, 78, 75];
                        }
                    if(data.cell.text.indexOf('EQUITY_CLOSE_SHORT') > -1) {
                        data.cell.styles.fillColor = [216, 78, 75];
                    }
                },

        // Footer
        var str = "Page " + doc.internal.getNumberOfPages()
        // Total page number plugin only available in jspdf v1.0+
        if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
            str = str + " of " + totalPagesExp;
        }
        doc.setFontSize(10);


        // jsPDF 1.4+ uses getWidth, <1.4 uses .width
        var pageSize = doc.internal.pageSize;
        var pageHeight = pageSize.height ? pageSize.height : pageSize.getHeight();
        doc.text(str, data.settings.margin.left, pageHeight - 10);
    },
    margin: {top: 100}
});


  // Total page number plugin only available in jspdf v1.0+
  if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
    doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
  }

  doc.save('tabled.pdf');
}

</script>
```

Hope someone has an idea, thank you!

EDIT: Here are pictures of what I have now and what I would like to have as an end result.

[Result now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEGU4.png)

[Desired result, where the entire row has a color based on cell value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdaJr.png)

Comment: You should be on the right track with using the didParseCell hook. What is the issue you are running into when trying to color entire rows? Maybe `data.cell.text.indexOf('EQUITY_CLOSE_LONG') > 0` is only true for certain cells and not for the entire row?

Comment: Your question can be better answered if you could elaborate more on what your desired results should be and also describe the incorrect results that you are currently generating. Including an image of the bad results and then describe how you want it to change to be correct would be helpful.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson thanks for the reply! I understand that my code now only colors the cells true to 'EQUITY_CLOSE_LONG', but what I'm looking for is the entire row color when a cell in the first column is true. I have added pictures of my results now and what my desired results are. Hope this clarifies better what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnH thanks for the reply, I've added pictures of what my result is now and what I'm looking for. Hope this clarifies more.

Comment: Aha! Have you tried something like this `data.row.index === 1` instead of `data.cell.text.indexOf('EQUITY_CLOSE_LONG') > -1`?

Comment: Try using a browser inspection tool ("Inspector" for Firefox or "Inspect" for Chrome) to analyze the CSS attribute settings applicable to the generated HTML. Those tools can also enable you to make CSS updates specific to your browser to test how CSS attribute updates changes the appearance of the displayed HTML.

Comment: My data is dynamic and will change every time someone changes the API request. I know `data.row.index === 1` works perfectly, but in my case I need something that works dynamically and I didn't manage to get that working with `data.row.index`.
I was hoping there would be a code for coloring a row, which I could use in my `if` statement.